# How to make text labels appear in pgfplots xbar stacked

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to have a stacked bar chart work like a pie chart, with the percentage and label appear in each rectangle. I can get the values appear with a percentage sign, but not the actual text. Maybe there's something else that needs to go as the argument to `nodes near coords`, or some other way entirely. Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=1.19\linewidth, axis lines=none, xbar stacked, nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}]
\addplot+[black,fill=white,xbar] plot coordinates {(10,0) [Homework]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white,xbar] plot coordinates {(10,0) [Quizzes]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white,xbar] plot coordinates {(20,0) [Midterm 1]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white,xbar] plot coordinates {(20,0) [Midterm 2]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white,xbar] plot coordinates {(40,0) [Final]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the text labels ("Homework", "Quizzes", etc) to appear inside or below each rectangle, perhaps rotated by some angle so that they fit in the available width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `\pgpflotspointmeta` for an `xbar` is, as you've seen, the x-value. To access the text you've added, you need to set `point meta=explicit symbolic`, which means that `pgfplots` will use whatever you have explicitly written in the coordinate list as the meta value, and that it is *not* interpreted as a number (that's the `symbolic` part).

To access the x-value in addition, you can use `visualization depends on`, as in this example:

[image: output of the code below]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  % needed to increase width a bit
  width=1.4\linewidth,
  axis lines=none,
  xbar stacked,
  % increased bar width to make room for text
  bar width=30pt,
  point meta=explicit symbolic,
  visualization depends on=x \as \XVal,
  nodes near coords={%
    \pgfmathprintnumber\XVal\% \\
    \tiny\pgfplotspointmeta
  },
  every node near coord/.style={
      % allows for linebreaks
      align=center
  } 
]
\addplot+[black,fill=white] coordinates {(10,0) [Homework]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white] coordinates {(10,0) [Quizzes]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white] coordinates {(20,0) [Midterm 1]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white] coordinates {(20,0) [Midterm 2]};
\addplot+[black,fill=white] coordinates {(40,0) [Final]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That's perhaps not ideal though, and it's also not that flexible (I couldn't find a way of storing the meta-value in a macro, as below). 
In the following example I changed the way coordinates are input, simply because that does make things easier, and more flexible

Note: You don't need the `plot` keyword when using `\addplot`. That is, use `\addplot +[..] coordinates`, not `\addplot +[..] plot coordinates`. And you don't need to specify `xbar` for each plot when you have `xbar stacked` in the `axis` options.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=1.19\linewidth,
  axis lines=none, 
  xbar stacked,
  % save number from first table column in macro \XVal
  visualization depends on=\thisrowno{0} \as \XVal,
  % save number from third table column in macro \MetaVal
  % "value" means that it is _not_ parsed as a number
  visualization depends on=value \thisrowno{2} \as \MetaVal,
  % use \XVal in nodes near coords
  nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\XVal}\%},
  % add a label to print the meta info
  every node near coord/.style={
    label={[anchor=west,rotate=-45]below:\MetaVal}
  }
]

\addplot +[black,fill=white] table[header=false,col sep=comma] {
10, 0, Homework
};
\addplot +[black,fill=white] table[header=false,col sep=comma] {
10, 0, Quizzes
};
\addplot +[black,fill=white] table[header=false,col sep=comma] {
20, 0, Midterm 1
};
\addplot +[black,fill=white] table[header=false,col sep=comma] {
20, 0, Midterm 2
};
\addplot +[black,fill=white] table[header=false,col sep=comma] {
40, 0, Final
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```